# ActiveMerchant Paypal Gateway/Express

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paypal, activemerchant

I'm trying to integrate ActiveMerchange and PaypalExpress into my site, but I'm getting confused along the way. I've googled all over the place and watched several RailsCasts, but am still a little confused.

In my app, I'm wanting to sell credits. The "products" to purchase are simply credits. They are not actual objects, nor are in the database, but are simply in a hash, for example:

```
# 1 credit is $5, 5 credits are $25
{
  '1' => 5,
  '5' => 25
}
```

I do not want to use a Cart system like it shows in many online tutorials, I simply want the user to be able to select an amount of credits from a dropdown list, click "Checkout with Paypal", purchase the credits, and have it update their account.

Can anyone guide me through this? I hope this isn't asking too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [Express Checkout](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ec).  This makes it very simple to process any amount you need no matter how you're calculating the total.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It doesn't answer my question, but you are the only response, so you're the chosen answer!

Comment: Did you need more help with Express Checkout Directly?  It involves 3 API calls:  SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails (optional), and DoExpressCheckoutPayment.

Comment: I was able to figure it out quite easily actually, thanks for the offer though